# detect if browser allows setting localStorage.setItem();

Tags: javascript, html

When using IE11 and using javascript's localStorage features, the browser console blocks javascript from being executed by throwing a message 'access denied' because of security settings within the browser.

Is there a way to detect via javascript of these settings are enabled?

I tried:

> if(localStorage.setItem('testvar','123')){ alert('ok');}else{
>   alert('not ok');}

but still caused the rest of the script to halt.

thank you

Comment: Wrap it in a `try { ... } catch(error) { ... }` block. I imagine that `localStorage` as an item still exists, even if it is blocked.

Answer (score 2):

```
function supports_html5_storage() {
  try {
    if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null)
        {
          localStorage.setItem("testitem",true);
          localStorage.removeItem("testitem");
          return true;
        }
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Source: [diveintohtml5](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

**EDIT:** Added `localStorage.setItem` to check, not only if it exists but if it is writable.

Comment: the question is not about localStorage support. Acctually it is about access to localStorage

Comment: This will in many cases also check access. A lot of browsers block even accessing the object itself. But, I do agree, the answer is incomplete and could be improved.

Comment: It does seem to work for detection :), so basically even though IE11 supports localStorage, depending on security settings the 'support' dissapears somehow

Comment: the problem with your additional code  "localStorage.setItem("testitem",true);" is that if you use that as an extra check, but the browser does not allow it, it will block the rest of the script. The inital code would not block the script, so I think the initial answer was better :)

Comment: @user2022678 the code is into a `try .. catch` block so the browser should't block the rest of the script.